# Filtering a panda dataframe based on value and time

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a panda dataframe like this

```
2011-5-5 12:43               noEvent          CarA      otherColumns...
2011-5-5 12:45               noEvent          CarA          ...
2011-5-5 12:49               EVENT            CarA          ...
2011-5-5 12:51               noEvent          CarA          ...
(no data - jumps in time)
2011-5-6 12:52               EVENT            CarA          ...
2011-5-6 12:59               noEvent          CarA          ...
2011-5-6 13:00               noEvent          CarA          ...
2011-5-5 12:43               noEvent          CarB          ...
2011-5-5 12:45               noEvent          CarB          ...
2011-5-5 12:49               noEvent          CarB          ...
2011-5-5 12:51               noEvent          CarB          ...
(no data - jumps in time)
2011-5-6 12:52               noEvent          CarB          ...
2011-5-6 12:52               EVENT            CarB          ...
2011-5-6 13:00               noEvent          CarB          ...
```

Explanation:

- The timestamp column is not linearly spaced
- There is 2 cars, A and B. The events from A are independent from B's events

I need to perform some calculation **+-2 minutes before and after** an event occured and for each car.

To do this, I am confused... How can I filter this dataframe?

The desired result would look like this

```
-2min
2011-5-5 12:49               EVENT            CarA          ...
+2min

-2min
2011-5-6 12:52               EVENT            CarA          ...
+2min

-2min
2011-5-6 12:52               EVENT            CarB          ...
+2min
```

Some info:

- You cannot mix events from CarA and CarB
- In future, the number of cars can be hundreds of thousands

I don't know where to start..

- What functions can I use?
- How can I group the events in "blocks" in order to proccess each 4 min  - block of records separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the Car column first and process every group as following:

Create the test data first:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
idx = pd.date_range("2016-03-01 10:00:00", "2016-03-01 20:00:00", freq="S")
idx = idx[np.random.randint(0, len(idx), 10000)].sort_values()
evt = np.array(["no event", "event"])[(np.random.rand(len(idx)) < 0.0005).astype(int)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"event":evt, "value":np.random.randint(0, 10, len(evt))}, index=idx)
```

find the event row and the row index of +/- 10 seconds:

```
event_time = df.index[df.event == "event"]
delta = pd.Timedelta(10, unit="s")

start_idx = df.index.searchsorted(event_time - delta).tolist()
end_idx = df.index.searchsorted(event_time + delta).tolist()
```

create the mask array:

```
mask = np.zeros(df.shape[0], dtype=bool)
evt_id = np.zeros(df.shape[0], dtype=int)
for i, (s, e) in enumerate(zip(start_idx, end_idx)):
    mask[s:e] = True
    evt_id[s:e] = i
```

use the mask array to filter rows, here I create a event_id column to group event:

```
df_event = df[mask]
df_event["event_id"] = evt_id[mask]
```

the output:

```
                        event  value  event_id
2016-03-01 13:51:48  no event      0         0
2016-03-01 13:51:51     event      8         0
2016-03-01 13:51:53  no event      3         0
2016-03-01 13:52:00  no event      1         0
2016-03-01 14:21:00  no event      2         1
2016-03-01 14:21:00  no event      5         1
2016-03-01 14:21:00  no event      0         1
2016-03-01 14:21:02  no event      1         1
2016-03-01 14:21:04  no event      2         1
2016-03-01 14:21:06  no event      0         1
2016-03-01 14:21:07     event      1         1
2016-03-01 14:21:16  no event      1         1
2016-03-01 14:21:16  no event      9         1
2016-03-01 15:09:42  no event      1         2
2016-03-01 15:09:49     event      7         2
2016-03-01 15:09:54  no event      3         2
2016-03-01 15:09:55  no event      3         2
2016-03-01 15:09:58  no event      5         2
2016-03-01 15:09:58  no event      9         2
2016-03-01 17:36:44  no event      8         3
2016-03-01 17:36:44  no event      2         3
2016-03-01 17:36:44  no event      9         3
2016-03-01 17:36:45  no event      2         3
2016-03-01 17:36:49     event      9         3
2016-03-01 17:36:50  no event      6         3
2016-03-01 17:36:54  no event      1         3
2016-03-01 17:36:56  no event      1         3
2016-03-01 18:51:37  no event      5         4
2016-03-01 18:51:37  no event      3         4
2016-03-01 18:51:42  no event      0         4
2016-03-01 18:51:47     event      9         4
2016-03-01 18:51:55  no event      4         4
```

Comment: hi @hyry, thanks for the code. Could you also share a code showing how to group by "car" column and proccess each group independently?

Comment: ps: I am still trying to understand each code block you provided..  :-)

Comment: hey @hyry, me again...

The code is indeed very clever. Good job. The only drawback is the message below:

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df_event["event_id"] = evt_id[mask]

Comment: @guilhermecgs, try this `df_event.loc[:, "event_id"] = evt_id[mask]`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the cross join merge, comparing an all events filtered dataframe and the full dataframe. Then subset records falling in the +/- 2 mins by same car:

Data frame setup *(example posted data)*

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['5/5/2011 12:43', '5/5/2011 12:45', '5/5/2011 12:49',
                            '5/5/2011 12:51', '5/6/2011 12:52', '5/6/2011 12:59', 
                            '5/6/2011 13:00', '5/5/2011 12:43', '5/5/2011 12:45', 
                            '5/5/2011 12:49', '5/5/2011 12:51', '5/6/2011 12:52',
                            '5/6/2011 12:52', '5/6/2011 13:00'],
                   'Event': ['noEvent', 'noEvent', 'EVENT', 'noEvent','EVENT',
                             'noEvent', 'noEvent', 'noEvent', 'noEvent', 'noEvent',
                             'noEvent', 'noEvent', 'EVENT', 'noEvent'],
                   'Car': ['CarA', 'CarA', 'CarA', 'CarA', 'CarA',
                           'CarA', 'CarA', 'CarB', 'CarB','CarB',
                           'CarB', 'CarB', 'CarB', 'CarB']})

    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

#      Car                Date    Event
# 0   CarA 2011-05-05 12:43:00  noEvent
# 1   CarA 2011-05-05 12:45:00  noEvent
# 2   CarA 2011-05-05 12:49:00    EVENT
# 3   CarA 2011-05-05 12:51:00  noEvent
# 4   CarA 2011-05-06 12:52:00    EVENT
# 5   CarA 2011-05-06 12:59:00  noEvent
# 6   CarA 2011-05-06 13:00:00  noEvent
# 7   CarB 2011-05-05 12:43:00  noEvent
# 8   CarB 2011-05-05 12:45:00  noEvent
# 9   CarB 2011-05-05 12:49:00  noEvent
# 10  CarB 2011-05-05 12:51:00  noEvent
# 11  CarB 2011-05-06 12:52:00  noEvent
# 12  CarB 2011-05-06 12:52:00    EVENT
# 13  CarB 2011-05-06 13:00:00  noEvent
```

Cross join *(returns full combination set between two pairings M X N)*

```
df['key'] = 1

# EVENTS DF
eventsdf = df[df['Event']=='EVENT']

# CROSS JOIN DF
crossdf = pd.merge(df, eventsdf, on='key')

crossdf = crossdf[((crossdf['Date_x'] <= crossdf['Date_y'] 
                               + datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)) &
                   (crossdf['Date_x'] >= crossdf['Date_y'] 
                               - datetime.timedelta(minutes=2))) &
                   (crossdf['Car_x'] == crossdf['Car_y'])].sort_values('Date_x')

finaldf = crossdf[['Car_x', 'Date_x', 'Event_x']].drop_duplicates().sort_values('Car_x')                      
finaldf.columns = ['Car', 'Date', 'Event']

#      Car                Date    Event
# 6   CarA 2011-05-05 12:49:00    EVENT
# 9   CarA 2011-05-05 12:51:00  noEvent
# 13  CarA 2011-05-06 12:52:00    EVENT
# 35  CarB 2011-05-06 12:52:00  noEvent
# 38  CarB 2011-05-06 12:52:00    EVENT
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, I´m really afraid of cross joins, since the dataframe is huge